# cannot create [Permission denied] executing script

Tags: redhat, permission-denied

I have searched a lot but a wasn't able a post that fits my needs.

I'm executing a script which creates a file redirecting the output of a sqlplus to a text file, the complete destination path has rwx permissions for the group, but I'm still geting the error. However if I use the same user than the script uses, and execute the "sqlplus >> file.dat" in command line, I have no error.

the issued line is as follows:

sqlplus -s $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$BBDD @$SQL_SCRIPT_FILE_PATH/sql_file.sql 20180621 | grep '|' >> $DATA_FILES_IN_PATH/file_20180621.dat

and the error:
scriptname.sh[25]: "complete_path"/file_20180621.dat: cannot create [Permission denied]

The permissions are 775 and both users, the owner and the executor are in the same group

Can any body help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you set permissions to 777 to the output file?

Comment: why should this affect? the permissions that prevent me to create the file, would be the dir ones, not the new file permissions, am I wrong?

Comment: I agree it should not. But currently it does not work.  Then either it's a bug in OS, or some of your assumptions are wrong. For example, could be that writing to the file is performed as another user which is not part of the group. Setting permissions to 777 and trying again can test this hypothesis.

Comment: You could also try running the program with strace and checking the exact error code. Might give you some pointers

Comment: Also try to simplify the problem and just try `echo "test" >> output.dat`. See if the issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

ok, it's SOLVED, it was due to the previous existence of identical named files, that were created by another user.

Thanks for your answers :)